# Etymology of Tor and Ext Functors

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology, homological-algebra

The names of the derived functors $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ seem quite cryptic to me. Does anyone know what these abbreviations stand for? I would be glad if someone could tell me where these names come from.

Comment: Tor comes from torsion, I think. The beginning of the second chapter in Weibel's book discusses this.

Comment: they come from their first versions. tor for torsion, ext for extensions

Comment: I think this question would be more interesting if you modified it to include asking about the history and origin of the functors.

Comment: For the history and origins of these functors, see here: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf [History of Homological Algebra by Weibel]

Comment: I find it amazing that one can get to know what Ext and Tor are and not the origin of their names!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ext stands for extension, as the group $\operatorname{Ext}^1(X,Y)$ parameterises extensions $Z$ fitting into a short exact sequence:

$$0\to Y\to Z\to X\to 0$$

modulo the trivial extension $X\oplus Y$.

According to Wikipedia, Tor is short for torsion, as if $r\in R$ is not a zero divisor and $B$ is an $R$-module, then $\operatorname{Tor}_1(R/(r),B)$ can be identified with the $r$-torsion part of $B$, i.e. $b\in B$ such that $rb=0$.

Comment: as for why torsion is called torsion, my google fu is too weak to bring up the relevant mathoverflow thread, but if i recall correctly it was to do with the fact that torsion in the algebraic sense leads to a nonorientability and "twisting" of a space onto itself

Comment: @exitingcorpse This .pdf might answer your question: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Torsion and Extension.............

Comment: Oh obviously. The dot dot dot's come off as arrogant.

Comment: @  Samuel Reid: "Body must be at least 30 characters" - I didn't have them :-)