# How to pronounce Ext

Tags: algebraic-topology, derived-functors

Maybe this is a dull question, but I'm curious about how people pronounce the word 'Ext', for the $\operatorname{Ext}^{n}_{R}$ functor; some people called it as 'ee-ex-tee', 'eksit', or even just an $n$-th derived functor of Hom, and personally I have called it as something like 'ekst', just as pronouncing 'extension'(analogously for Tor as an abbreviation of torsion). Are there any commonly-adopted ways of pronouncing Ext?

Comment: People read it 'ee-ex-tee'?!?!

Comment: @Marino Suarez-Alvarez: I heard some people calling it so, even at the seminar in my University I entered...but most people around me called it as ekst or just as the derived functor of Hom.

Comment: Do they also pronounce $\operatorname{Tor}$ as "tee-oh-are" and $\sin$ as "ess-ee-enn"?

Comment: I haven't heard them pronouncing Tor and sin, but I don't think that they'll call Tor like that way...I feel like 'ext' seems more 'irregular' to pronounce compared to 'tor', and I suspect this is one of the reasons that some people (whose first language is not English) call Ext in that odd way...Also I haven't seen any people reading sin as ess-ai-enn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel the most obvious and simple pronunciation would be the "ext" part of "extension," just as you said. It is easy to say, short, and quite unambiguous as far as 3 character names go.

Comment: and it is actually named *Ext* because it measures extensions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433796/etymology-of-tor-and-ext I'd actually go a little further and say that this is the way it should be said.

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer, user184794! I was quite surprised when I heard some professors and graduate students in algebraic geometry or topology called it in some different ways, and suddenly became curious about this. Also thanks for the link, hjhjhj57!